# window.open does not work correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open

i have a big problem with IE (tested versions 6 & 8) issue. Window.open method works correctly in FF, Opera, Chrome. IE opens new window, but loads the same url in main window.
I know one solution can be to remove url from href, but i need it for JS turn off case. Also i need positioning for new window.

IE "error console" says: Access denied.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function regForm()
{
var left = Math.abs((window.innerWidth - 550) / 2);
var top = Math.abs((window.innerHeight - 600) / 2);
window.open("http://somepage.html", "Signin", "width=550,height=600,scrollbars=1").moveTo(left, top);
}           
</script>
<a class="ibm-b1-bttn" href="http://somepage.html" onclick="javascript:regForm(); return false;">Register Now</a>
```

Please help me, this is very important for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried removing the `moveTo()`? -- I suspect that's more likely the issue than the `window.open()` itself.

Comment: The problem isn't with `window.open()`, it's with the way the event handler is working.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `<a>` so that it's "href" value is just "#"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try referencing the URL without the HTTP? so `somepage.html`, or `\somepage.html` depending on where the file resides on your server?

Comment: This will not help, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

Unchain the windows function calls and see which one it's actually giving you the error on:

```
var myWin = window.open("http://somepage.html", "Signin", "width=550,height=600,scrollbars=1");
myWin.moveTo(left, top);
```

window.open should not give you that error.  I'm betting it's the moveTo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this work around to fix it.  First open a blank new window, move it, then change the location.  It appears to have something to do with IE security issues:

Anchor Tag:

```
<a class="ibm-b1-bttn" href="#" onclick="regForm();">Register Now</a>
```

JS Function:

```
function regForm() {
        var left = Math.abs((window.innerWidth - 550) / 2);
        var top = Math.abs((window.innerHeight - 600) / 2);
        var win = window.open("", "Signin", "width=550,height=600,scrollbars=1")
        win.moveTo(left, top);
        win.location = "http://somepage.html";
    }
```